# Copying files on a daily basis

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows, powershell, batch-file

I would like to copy some files on a daily basis from one folder to another on a server.
Each file will be kept for one week then deleted.
Which is the best way to achieve this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to use [RoboCopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc733145(v=ws.10).aspx) either in a script or with the [GUI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/robocoprobocopy/) (in conjunction with the Windows Task Scheduler).

Or maybe you want to go the [Windows Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx) route, although I personally think for a simple copy job it's a bit overkill.

(Broad answer for a broad question :-) )

Answer (score 0):

I create a VBS for that:

```
Option Explicit 

Dim oFso
Dim sStartPath1, sStartPath2, sStartPath3, sZielPath1
Dim sDatenAlter1, sDatenAlter2, sDatenAlter3
Dim sLogFile
Dim oTxtStm
Const ForAppending = 8


sStartPath1  = "C:\PTC\PDFs" 
sDatenAlter1 = 2

sStartPath2  = "C:\PTC\DXFs"
sDatenAlter2 = 2

sStartPath3  = "C:\PTC\STEPs"
sDatenAlter3 = 2

sZielPath1    = "C:\PTC\Old_Files\"


sLogFile = "C:\PTC\Old_Files\Logfile_Automove.txt"

Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set oTxtStm = oFso.OpenTextFile(sLogFile, 8, True) 

oTxtStm.WriteLine " "
oTxtStm.WriteLine "--------------- Beginn, " & Now & " ---------------" 
oTxtStm.WriteLine " "


If oFso.FolderExists(sStartPath1) Then 
Call ReadFolder(sStartPath1, sDatenAlter1) 
Else 
oTxtStm.WriteLine "Keine Dateien gefunden" 
End If 

If oFso.FolderExists(sStartPath2) Then 
Call ReadFolder(sStartPath2, sDatenAlter2) 
Else 
oTxtStm.WriteLine "Keine Dateien gefunden" 
End If 

If oFso.FolderExists(sStartPath3) Then 
Call ReadFolder(sStartPath3, sDatenAlter3) 
Else 
oTxtStm.WriteLine "Keine Dateien gefunden" 
End If

oTxtStm.WriteLine " "
oTxtStm.WriteLine "--------------- Ende, " & Now & " ---------------" 
oTxtStm.WriteLine " "
oTxtStm.Close 



Set oFso = Nothing 
Set oTxtStm = Nothing 
'MsgBox "Fertig, Logdatei wurde gespeichert unter: " & vbNewLine & sLogFile 



Function ReadFolder(sPath, sAlter)
Dim oFld 'nimmt das Ordnerobjekt (Folder) auf 
Dim oF 'nimmt das Dateiobjekt (File) auf 
Dim nFCount, nErrNum , nFCount1, nFCount2
Dim alterfile 'Bestimmt das Alter der Datei
Dim alterfolder 'Bestimmt das Alter des Ordners
Dim size ' Bestimmt die grösse des Ordners

On Error Resume Next 
'hier wird Fehler 70 ausgelöst, falls kein Zugriff besteht 
'Ohne Zugriff ist ein Auflisten der Files natürlich nicht möglich 
nFCount = oFso.GetFolder(sPath).Files.Count 
nErrNum = Err.Number 
Err.Clear 
On Error Goto 0 

If nErrNum = 0 Then 

'MsgBox "Ordner: " & sPath & " - Anzahl Dateien: " & nFCount

For Each oF In oFso.GetFolder(sPath).Files 
'... hier die Anweisung zum verschieben der Dateien
    On Error Resume Next 
    alterfile = 0
    alterfile = alterfile + DateDiff("d", oF.DateCreated, Now)
    If alterfile > sAlter Then
        oTxtStm.WriteLine "Die Datei : (" & oF.Path & ") --- Wurde verschoben"
        oFso.CopyFile oF.Path, sZielPath1 & oF.Name, true
        oFso.deletefile oF.path, True
    Else
        'oTxtStm.WriteLine "Die Datei : " & oF.Path & " erfüllt die Kriterien nicht, um verschoben zu werden."
    End If 
Next 


ElseIf nErrNum = 70 Then 
oTxtStm.WriteLine "*** Fehler: " & sPath & " - Zugriff verweigert -"                    'Logeintrag bei Fehler 70, falls erwünscht
Else 
oTxtStm.WriteLine "*** Fehler: " & sPath & " - Fehlernummer: " & Err.Number & " -"      'Logeintrag bei sonst. Fehler, falls erwünscht 
End If
End Function
```

All older Files then **sDatenAlter** from Path **sStartPath** will be moved to **sZielPath1**.

A LogFile will be written in **sLogFile**.

Answer (score -1):

Well i recommend you make a new project / windows service in your desired language and install the service on server... you could put in your new logic easly the logic to copy on some interval files and delete them ... being a service is not related to user accounts so if the server is running so is your service....

Comment: A scheduled task is way better than deploying a service.